# Using org-capture-templates to schedule a TODO for the day after today

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode, I know how to create a todo and use the timestamp so that it is scheduled for today. How do I schedule it for tomorrow? Unfortunately I don't know Elisp and don't have time right now to learn it. Here is my .emacs file:

```
 (setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Agenda Todo" entry
     (file+headline "c:/Org/agenda.org" "Agenda")
     "\n\n** TODO %?\nSCHEDULED: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>" 
     :empty-lines 1)
```

I would need to replace the %m-%d %a with a value incremented by one day.

Comment: I'd actually wondered about this back when I was creating my capture templates, but never gotten to the point of figuring it out until now.  Additionally, %t will provide you with the equivalent of <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>> through template expansion, if you simply want today's date. %^t will prompt for a date, defaulting to today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working off Juancho's answer* I was able to come up with a valid timestamp.

The following will provide an org-created timestamp.

```
"[...]SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+1d\"))"
```

`org-read-date` generates a date and `+1d` shifts it one day in the future. `nil t` tells it to not include HH:MM time and to convert the date into an internal TIME representation.

`org-insert-time-stamp` takes TIME and converts it to a timestamp using the normal org-mode format (including weekday abbreviation)

*The answer does not work because
`<%(org-read-date nil nil \"+1d\")>"`
results in
`<YYYY-MM-DD>`

---

#### Update

A timestamp of  is now valid in Org mode (it was added to allow for entering timestamps from outside org-mode where they would not automatically be able to calculate the day of the week I believe).

Therefore Juancho's answer would work as well.

Comment: How would one automatically prompt the agenda instead?

Answer (score 4):

This should work for your template string:

```
"\n\n** TODO %?\nSCHEDULED: <%(org-read-date nil nil \"+1d\")>"
```

`org-read-date` generates a timestamp; `+1d` means tomorrow.

Comment: I just tried this. It doesn't work because a timestamp requires the day of the week to be valid for scheduling.

Answer (score 2):

And further more, if you want a repeatable template, which generates a time stamp like:

```
SCHEDULED: <2012-08-17 Fri .+1d>
```

you may use this one:

```
SCHEDULED:%(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t) nil nil nil nil \" .+1d\")
```