# Org mode capture

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to make a 'class' template for org-capture.

What I want is to easily make this kind of entry:

```
* TODO <course>: Week <week> Lecture <number>
  SCHEDULED: %^T
** TODO prepare for class: <course>-<week>-<number>
   SCHEDULED: <two days before T> DEADLINE: <one day before T>
** TODO review class: <course>-<week>-<number>
   SCHEDULED: <one day after T> DEADLINE: <two days after T>
```

Currently, I have this template.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
   '(
    ("c" "Class" entry (file "~/sydbox/personal/workflow/class.txt")
         "* TODO %^{Course}: Week %^{Week} Lecture %^{Number}\n  SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t nil nil nil \" \"))\n location: %^{location} %?\n** TODO %\\1: prepare lecture %\\3 from week %\\2\n   DEADLINE: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"-1d\")) SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"-2d\"))\n** TODO %\\1: review lecture %\\3 from week %\\2\n   DEADLINE: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+2d\")) SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+1d\"))\n")
    ("e" "Exercise session" entry (file "~/sydbox/personal/workflow/class.txt")
     ))
```

However, now I have no idea how to input the dates. The date and time of the course should be prompted for (_only_once_).

Comment: Here is a related thread, which may give someone a jump-start towards answering this interesting question in the current thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986935/using-org-capture-templates-to-schedule-a-todo-for-the-day-after-today  The eventual answer to this question will probably be using the variable `org-last-changed-timestamp` which stores the last time-stamp that was used, so the user doesn't have to select the date again.

Comment: NOTE:  This current question / thread has also been cross-posted to Superuser:  http://superuser.com/questions/788329/org-mode-capture

Comment: Here is a link to some code I wrote / modified a few month ago, which enables the custom creation of `org-mode` entries:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22419713/2112489  I realize that the original poster probably wants to keep it simple by using `org-capture-templates`; however, I wanted to point out that there are other ways to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works for me.  It first defines a custom function to create the template (`org-capture-class`), which calculates the date as necessary and is easier on the eyes than the in-line string (note that it relies on `cl-lib`, so make sure that's loaded).  It then calls that function in the template itself, niling out if any of the fields are empty (*updated in response to comment*):

```
(defun org-capture-class ()
  "Capture a class template for org-capture."
  (cl-labels ((update (date days)
                      (format-time-string
                       (car org-time-stamp-formats)
                       (seconds-to-time (+ (time-to-seconds date)
                                           (* days 86400))))))
    (let ((course   (read-string "Course: " nil nil '(nil)))
          (week     (read-string "Week: " nil nil '(nil)))
          (lecture  (read-string "Lecture No.: " nil nil '(nil)))
          (date     (org-read-date nil t))
          (location (read-string "Location: " nil nil '(nil))))
      (when (and course week lecture date location)
        (concat (format "* TODO %s: Week %s Lecture %s\n"
                        course week lecture)
                (format "  SCHEDULED: %s\n" (update date 0))
                (format "  Location: %s %%?\n" location)
                (format "** TODO %s: prepare lecture %s from week %s\n"
                        course lecture week)
                (format "   DEADLINE: %s SCHEDULED: %s\n"
                        (update date -1) (update date -2))
                (format "** TODO %s: review lecture %s from week %s\n"
                        course lecture week)
                (format "   DEADLINE: %s SCHEDULED: %s\n"
                        (update date 2) (update date 1)))))))

(setq org-capture-templates
   '(("c" "Class" entry
      (file "~/sydbox/personal/workflow/class.txt")
      #'org-capture-class)
     ("e" "Exercise session" entry
      (file "~/sydbox/personal/workflow/class.txt"))))
```

Comment: Wauw! thanks. However, this does not seem to be working. Try building the agenda view. All the scedules and deadlines are on the same day.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what your code was trying to do.  The updated version should work as you explained in your comment: schedules and deadlines are now appropriately 1 or 2 days around the class date.

Comment: You're welcome!  I'd meant to learn more about org-capture, and this puzzle provided a nice excuse to do so.  As an aside, unless you're waiting to see if there are alternate answers forthcoming (no offense taken if so), consider manually awarding the bounty to remove the question from the "Featured" tab.

Comment: I was trying, 9 hours ago, but I couldn't yet. If I can ever help you with some haskell code, let me know!